# How to create a single rowed pandas dataframe with geopandas?

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas

I'm trying to export the lines from a polyline shapefile as individual shapefiles. When I am trying to loop through the rows of the gpd dataframe, it indicates that pd series do not have the attribute (to_file) which appears to be available for dataframes.

```
for i in range(0,5):
    dftemp = df.iloc[i,:]
    print(type(dftemp))
    dftemp.to_file(path + '//' + 'z' + str(listi.value[0].split('.')[0]) + '_' + str(i) + '.shp')
```

> AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'to_file'

Thanks

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Dataframes don't have a `to_file` method, did you mean `to_csv()`?

Comment: Or did you mean to use the native _geopandas_ methods, in which case you need to be operating on a GeoSeries, not a regular pandas series to use [geopandas.GeoSeries.to_file](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoSeries.to_file.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
for i in range(0,5):
    dftemp = df.iloc[[i],:]
    print(type(dftemp))
    dftemp.to_file(path + '//' + 'z' + str(listi.value[0].split('.')[0]) + '_' + str(i) + '.shp')
```

`df.iloc[i,:]` returns a Series, but `df.iloc[[i],:]` a GeoDataFrame, which is needed for `to_file`

Comment: thank you so much :)